# Using REGEXP within MySQL to find a certain number within a comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a list of numbers in some fields in a table, for example something like this:

```
2033,1869,1914,1913,19120,1911,1910,1909,1908,1907,1866,1921,1922,1923
```

Now, I'm trying to do a query to check if a number is found in the row, however, I can't use `LIKE` as then it may return false positives as if I did a search for `1912` in the above field I would get a result returned because of the number `19120`, obviously we don't want that - we can't append or prepend a comma as the start/end numbers don't have them.

So, onto using `REGEXP` I go... I tried this, but it doesn't work (it returns a result):

```
SELECT * FROM cat_listing WHERE cats REGEXP '[^0-9]*1912[^0-9]*';
```

I imagine why it still finds something is because of the `*` quantifier; it found `[^0-9]` 0 times **AFTER** `1912` so it considers it a match.

I'm not sure how to modify it to do what I want.

Comment: How about not storing comma-separated list in a field?  This is what parent-child relationship in a database is for.

Comment: Did you try with word boundaries: `SELECT * FROM cat_listing WHERE cats REGEXP '[[:<:]]1912[[:>:]]';`?

Comment: @AleksG I'm aware of that, but for this situation this is the best method and a parent child relationship isn't needed.

Comment: @stribizhev That seems to work great. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it seems word boundaries are necessary:

```
SELECT * FROM cat_listing WHERE cats REGEXP '[[:<:]]1912[[:>:]]';
```

`[[:<:]]` is the beginning of a word and `[[:>:]]` is the end. See [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

> `[[:<:]], [[:>:]]`
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of >words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not >preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric >character in the alnum class or an underscore (`_`).

Answer (score 2):

You have another option called [find_in_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM cat_listing WHERE find_in_set('1912', cats) <> 0;
```

> Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Comment: This is by far the best answer.  I don't know why it was not chosen.  But then again, someone who stores lists in comma-separated fields is probably a bit weak on SQL and data representation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It wasn't chosen because it wasn't available as an answer when I selected the other answer, simple as that. Additionally, you have no idea how I am using this data so don't make assumptions that I should be storing it in another manner.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a regex just because the column value has no comma at either end:

```
SELECT
  cats
FROM cat_listing
WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',', cats, ','), ',1912,')
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f20d3/1).
Please comment if adjustment / further detail is required.